# Washbasin Tap not working properly and no water pressure. Refer images

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

just shifted to a house and after moving in got to know about the tap situation. The house owner hasn't shown up since ages as per current roommates. Kindly view the image and suggest a solution to the low water pressure situation. I have clicked a picture of the section where water outlet is and another showing the water pressure. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a clogged aerator. Unscrew it and flush it out with water. Use a pliers and wrap the aerator in a cloth as to not scratch the finish.

Comment: If you remove the aerator (approx cylindrical part on the outflow end of the faucet), first close the drain or lay a cloth over it. There are little parts in the aerator which can fall. You may be able to clear it by holding the parts in with your thumb and running water from the tap backwards through the aerator.

Comment: LOL .. that's what traps are for ... just kidding Jim.